# Is it possible to have non-metallic electronics?

Tags: realism, mission-impossible, mission-impossible-rogue-nation

One of the showpieces of MI:RN is an attempt by Ethan Hunt to free-dive (meaning swimming without an auxiliary oxygen supply) into a water cooled computer.

The necessity for the free-dive is predicated by the pretext that the sensors will detect 'any metal' (notice we're not just talking non-conductive or non ferrous, but *any metal*) that passes through the intake.

**With this in mind, how is it possible for Ethan to have an electronic interface built into his suit, indicating his remaining oxygen supply?**

[image]

Whilst it's a relatively simple component, is it possible to create such electronics without the use of metals?

Is this based on an existing technology?

Answer (score 7):

Non metallic circuits are possible, but mostly improbable in practical or consumer levels. It's relatively new.

First part already has consumer usage. OLEDS, Organic Light Emitting Diodes are non metallic screen technology. Can be organic or polymer based.

Second is ORBs, Organic Radical Batteries, or a newer tech/version, Organic Redux Flow Batteries. Again Organic or Polymer based.

Third is ICPs, intrinsically conducting polymers, used as conductive material (wires or traces). There are traditional non metallic conductors too, like graphite (pencil lead).

Finally OFets, Organic Field Effect Transistors. Transistors being the heart of any Integrated Circuit.

While Mission Impossible clearly uses fictionally advanced ideas of it (border line science fiction), a non metallic electrical circuit is not impossible.